# Высота адресной строки браузера

Tags: html, jquery, css

Можно ли каким-нибудь способом узнать высоту адресной строки браузера на телефоне (jquery)?

Нужно, чтобы высота баннера занимала 100% высоты экрана, но если проскроллить до ее исчезновения то все, как надо, но при загрузке скроллить не вариант.

Comment: Мне кажется, у вас [ошибка молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy). Вам точно нужна именно высота адресной строки в мобильном браузере а не, скажем, высота видимой области экрана? Не очень понятно, что с этим значением вообще можно сделать - страница на адресную строку не очень влияет.

Comment: @yeputons, нужно ,чтобы высота баннера занимала 100% высоты экрана, но если проскроллить до ее исчезновения то все, как надо,но при загрузке скроллить не вариант

Comment: «если проскроллить до ее исчезновения то все, как надо, но при загрузке скроллить не вариант» — не понимаю вот эту часть.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, после срабатывания события load  документ уже будет проскроллен, но уже решил вопрос, спасибо

Comment: @NickVolynkin как решили вопрос?

Comment: @АлексейОбоянский я не решал этот вопрос, пишите Ristek