# Определить скрыта ли адресная строка в мобильном браузере

Tags: javascript, html, css

Моя верстка идет с размером 100vh по высоте в мобильном браузере. Занимает всю высоту экрана.

Но если показана адресная строка, то часть контента выходить за экран.

Что бы увидеть весь контент нужно немного сдвинуть экран вверх,
что бы адресная строка исчезла и тогда отображается весь контент целиком.

Но что бы пользователь понял, что экран нужно сдвинуть, я ему показываю уведомление об этом.

Вопрос в том как детектировать, что адресная строка скрыта.(что бы уведомление скрыть)
Возможно есть параметры размеров которые можно проверить.

Возможно есть вариант загрузить страницу сразу без строки.
Или прокрутить её автоматически.

([тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/689948/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) человек пишет что решил, но не сказал как)

Comment: как вариант в лоб - вы можете определить через javascript размер области экрана своей страницы и сравнить с какими-то заданными значениями (разрешений мобильных устройств не так то и много) и будете знать соответствует ли размер заранее заданному или нет, если нет - адресная строка скрыта - но это все таки топорно и в лоб

Comment: 100vh не всегда правильно высчитывается, используйте 100%

Comment: лучше вам просто сверстать всё адаптивно. Под любую ширину и высоту экранов

Comment: Будет прыгать адаптивная по высоте верстка..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно создать невидымый блок для проверки у которого высота `100%` и когда разница с высотой блока у которого высота `100vh` минимальна(т.к. есть статус бар ~20px) - считать что адресная строка скрыта.

Пример:

```
<div class="vh"></div>
<div class="perc"></div>

<script>
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
    window.addEventListener('load', resize);

    function resize() {
        let vh = document.querySelector('.vh');
        vh.innerHTML = vh.offsetHeight;

        let perc = document.querySelector('.perc');
        perc.innerHTML = perc.offsetHeight
    }
</script>

<style>
    div {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 0.5;
        font-size: 3em;
        color: blue;
    }

    .vh {
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: green;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .perc {
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: red;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

В iframe не работает, поэтому вот [пример работы](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBVHG.jpg)

Comment: Спасибо. Очень помогли.